# Dynamic Javascript in IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm using this code while looping in IG to get specific value :

```
empName = gridView.model.getValue(r, "ENAME");
```

Can I have a dynamic code to get all IG columns values without fixed column reference? like that  :

```
 Col1Value = gridView.model.getValue(r, col1);

 Col2Value = gridView.model.getValue(r, col2);
```

to be generic code to be used in any IG?

Comment: I have found a function to loop through all the records, but I couldnt find another to loop through the columns, did you find anything?

Comment: The same issue dear i search for it , looping through columns